# Openvpn client log file

Tags: logging, raspberry-pi, openvpn

I have set up a openvpn client (version 2.3.12) on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian 7 whezzy) and I configured a `vpntest.conf` file in the folder `/etc/openvpn`. The connection is working when I call it with `sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/vpntest.conf`

But when I set autostart in `/etc/default/openvpn` to `AUTOSTART="vpntest"` the connection is not working. Is there any log file I can check for what is wrong?
I get nothing for `grep vpn /var/log/syslog`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can output the logs by changing the OPTARGS value in **/etc/default/openvpn**

```
# Append output to /var/log/syslog
OPTARGS="--syslog"

# Output to /var/log/my_openvpn_log. Existing contents of /var/log/my_openvpn_log will be deleted
OPTARGS="--log /var/log/my_openvpn_log"

# Append output to /var/log/my_openvpn_log
OPTARGS="--log-append /var/log/my_openvpn_log"
```